# How to fix Truecrypt MBR using Command Prompt or Linux live USB?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, truecrypt, mbr

I was playing with TrueCrypt and decided to make a fresh installation of Windows 7 from USB stick.

Unfortunately Windows 7 installer: "setup was unable to create a new system partition"

My entire HDD has been formatted and is visible as 320GB unallocated space, but no fdisk nor Windows 7 installer nor Windows XP installer could help. *(Windows XP doesn't even see the HDD, it sees only USB stick and says "not enough space to install")*

It may be related to **Truecrypt and pre-boot authentification, boot loader and/or MBR**. As I don't have optical device I could not have created rescue disk. Right now I need a rescue of some kind, supposingly by **erasing/fixing MBR** using Linux live USB or using Command Promt.

Another approach is to click "repair your comuter" menu from Windows 7 installer then click "restore your computer", then click OK upon error and get access to Command Prompt.

Yet another another approach is to start computer without Linux USB I receive this:

```
error:unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as my laptop is kind of not fully operational now.

**UPDATE**: This was asked long time ago, ended up formatting everything (eventually it worked using different bootable USB)...

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Win7 jumpdrive, select the "Repair your computer" option. Start a command prompt, then:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #
clean
```

The `clean` command will wipe all of the partitions from the drive, including the MBR.

If it still doesn't work, you can try `clean all` - 0-out the sectors on the drive (takes ages, don't do this with an SSD).

Comment: DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk. But still the same error: "setup was unable to create a new system partition", trying another Windows 7 image...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can make a ubuntu usb live, and use commands as below to erase MBR:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=1`

this will erase first 512B @ beginning of you disk /dev/sda(carefully change it to your hdd).